# Why my body (restsharp library) is incorrect?

Tags: c#, restsharp

Original curl:

```
 -d 'client_id={client_id}'
```

My c# code:

```
Body body = new Body()
            {
                client_id = "20...8351"
            };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body, Formatting.Indented);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
MessageBox.Show(json);
request.AddJsonBody(json);
```

In response I get communicate that client_id doesn't match to my account. I am 100% sure that it's correct, because in curl tester it works good. I think that it's problem with `json` variable format. Have you any suggestions?

Comment: client_id is really in your body? not in url?

Comment: Yes, as api documentation says.

Comment: @BartekMaćczak AddJsonBody expects object to serialize, not serialized object.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:
Against AddJsonBody I used AddParameter